# Two " Array to string conversion" notices (Prestashop)

Tags: php, arrays, string, prestashop, notice

I'm not so sure whether it is smart to post both problems in one question, but lets try:

So, I was checking my server's error log and it still has two notices, both about "Array to string conversion in [...]".

The first line should be this:

```
 $replace = $route['keywords'][$key]['prepend'].$params[$key].$route['keywords'][$key]['append'];
```

Context:

```
        // Build an url which match a route
    if ($this->use_routes || $force_routes) {
        $url = $route['rule'];
        $add_param = array();

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($route['keywords'][$key])) {
                if (!isset($this->default_routes[$route_id]['keywords'][$key])) {
                    $add_param[$key] = $value;
                }
            } else {
                if ($params[$key]) {
                    $replace = $route['keywords'][$key]['prepend'].$params[$key].$route['keywords'][$key]['append'];
                } else {
                    $replace = '';
                }
                $url = preg_replace('#\{([^{}]*:)?'.$key.'(:[^{}]*)?\}#', $replace, $url);
            }
        }
        $url = preg_replace('#\{([^{}]*:)?[a-z0-9_]+?(:[^{}]*)?\}#', '', $url);
        if (count($add_param)) {
            $url .= '?'.http_build_query($add_param, '', '&');
        }
    }
```

The second one is this line:

```
                $uri_path = __PS_BASE_URI__.$id_image.($type ? '-'.$type : '').$theme.'/'.$name.'.jpg';
```

as part of this:

```
        // legacy mode or default image
    $theme = ((Shop::isFeatureActive() && file_exists(_PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_.$ids.($type ? '-'.$type : '').'-'.(int)Context::getContext()->shop->id_theme.'.jpg')) ? '-'.Context::getContext()->shop->id_theme : '');
    if ((Configuration::get('PS_LEGACY_IMAGES')
        && (file_exists(_PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_.$ids.($type ? '-'.$type : '').$theme.'.jpg')))
        || ($not_default = strpos($ids, 'default') !== false)) {
        if ($this->allow == 1 && !$not_default) {
            $uri_path = __PS_BASE_URI__.$ids.($type ? '-'.$type : '').$theme.'/'.$name.'.jpg';
        } else {
            $uri_path = _THEME_PROD_DIR_.$ids.($type ? '-'.$type : '').$theme.'.jpg';
        }
    } else {
        // if ids if of the form id_product-id_image, we want to extract the id_image part
        $split_ids = explode('-', $ids);
        $id_image = (isset($split_ids[1]) ? $split_ids[1] : $split_ids[0]);
        $theme = ((Shop::isFeatureActive() && file_exists(_PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_.Image::getImgFolderStatic($id_image).$id_image.($type ? '-'.$type : '').'-'.(int)Context::getContext()->shop->id_theme.'.jpg')) ? '-'.Context::getContext()->shop->id_theme : '');
        if ($this->allow == 1) {
            $uri_path = __PS_BASE_URI__.$id_image.($type ? '-'.$type : '').$theme.'/'.$name.'.jpg';
        } else {
            $uri_path = _THEME_PROD_DIR_.Image::getImgFolderStatic($id_image).$id_image.($type ? '-'.$type : '').$theme.'.jpg';
        }
    }

    return $this->protocol_content.Tools::getMediaServer($uri_path).$uri_path;
}

public function getMediaLink($filepath)
{
    return $this->protocol_content.Tools::getMediaServer($filepath).$filepath;
}
```

PHP is not my strength, so I have no idea what to do :/
Also I found some other questions about Array to string notices, but it seemed to me like you can't solve them the same way...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: check by `print($route['keywords'][$key]['prepend']);print($params[$key].$route['keywords'][$key]['append'])` what they print. Array or string? same for second one and then you can adjust your code accordingly

Comment: Sorry to ask, but...how do I test this? :D

Comment: i have no idea of prestashop, but before that line code (first one) if you write this above code then may be on page or somewhere you see the output.

Comment: The first one should create a friendly URL, I guess, like: .../de/import/7688-keramik-schiffschale-percy.html

Answer (score 1):

This error is appearing because some of the variables in these two lines are supposed to be String but they are actually array.

You need to print all the variables used in these 2 lines using the var_dump() function of PHP, this will tell you which of the variables are actually an Array, but they are supposed to be a String as per your code.

On the basis of the output, you need to modify your code to fix the issue.

Comment: Sounds good, but I still have to ask: How do I do this? I created a new file with this code, added e.g. var_dump($uri_path) but that doesn't seem to work. Sorry, but I'm still very fresh to php :D